# How to disable firestore persistence when initializing firestore in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Because of bugs in firestore (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1642) we need to disable persistence for iOS devices.

All the documentation I can find says to do (variations of) this:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
firestore.settings({ persistence: false });
```

(from https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1143)

and, that we have to do this before any other firestore calls are made.

However, we are initializing firestore this way, in our "main" `app.module.ts`:

```
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(credentials),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
```

So, where would I put code to set persistence to false, and how would I import what I need to import to make that happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default persistence disabled. That's why you write:

```
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(credentials),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
```

you get disabled persistence.

To enable persistence you must write:

```
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(credentials),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
```

That's why you nothing to do for disabled persistence in your case.

Comment: this does not work even tho docs say it does

Answer (score -1):

The way that I have done this is pass in firebase configuration through initialize app.  I store that configuration in the "environments" folder.  I see that yours is called credentials.

```
export const environment = {
firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "https://some-database-name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storage-bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789",
    persistance: false
  }
```

}

```
imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
]
```